# Is is possible to have a nested OR condition inside EXISTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, logic, where-clause

I'm in the process of getting data from a table where the condition must be "Table1 AND (Table2 OR Table3 OR Table4)".

Here is my current query without the needed condition:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 P.RId 
FROM dbo.PD P
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM dbo.PTB PB
    INNER JOIN dbo.PTBI I on I.PTBId = PB.PTBId
    WHERE PB.RId = P.RId
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM dbo.AAD AB
    INNER JOIN dbo.CPD CP ON CP.RId = P.RId AND CP.CId = AB.CId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cl C on C.CltId = CP.ClId
) 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM dbo.AD A
    INNER JOIN dbo.CPD CP ON CP.RId = A.RId AND CP.CId = A.CId AND A.RId = P.RId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cl C ON C.ClId = CP.ClId
) 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM dbo.AAD AB
    INNER JOIN dbo.CPD CP ON CP.RId = P.RId AND CP.CId = AB.CId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cl C ON C.ClId = CP.ClId
)
```

The 2nd, 3rd, and 4th EXISTS condition in the query must be "(Table2 OR Table3 OR Table4)" condition. I don't how to implement this logic in SQL maybe someone could help?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, there is no point putting a `TOP` in an `EXISTS`; SQL Server will "short circuit" as soon as it finds the first row.

Comment: `TOP 1 1` is such a weird pattern to me. Whenever you have `TOP` without `ORDER BY` you should give it a good sniff.

Comment: Just change the proper ones to ORs and put parentheses around them, exactly as you did in your description.

Answer (score 0):

Just `OR` together the last 3 `EXISTS` conditions:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000 P.RId 
FROM dbo.PD P
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.PTB PB
    INNER JOIN dbo.PTBI I ON I.PTBId = PB.PTBId
    WHERE PB.RId = P.RId
) AND (
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.AAD AB
        INNER JOIN dbo.CPD CP ON CP.RId = P.RId AND CP.CId = AB.CId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Cl C on C.CltId = CP.ClId
    ) OR
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.AD A
        INNER JOIN dbo.CPD CP ON CP.RId = A.RId AND CP.CId = A.CId AND A.RId = P.RId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Cl C ON C.ClId = CP.ClId
    ) OR
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.AAD AB
        INNER JOIN dbo.CPD CP ON CP.RId = P.RId AND CP.CId = AB.CId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Cl C ON C.ClId = CP.ClId
    )
);
-- ORDER BY clause goes here
```

Note that using `TOP` in the outer query without using `ORDER BY` does not make much sense.  In the inner exists queries, there is no point to using `TOP`.

Comment: I forgot to add, in the EXISTS there must be at least 1 record so that's why I added TOP 1. I'll try your solution. Thank you!

Comment: @user9575720 `EXISTS` by definition means the query returns at least one record.